# How to set application icon in eletron-vue js

Tags: vuejs2, electron, electron-builder, electron-packager, electron-vue

I am working with electron-vue js for building cross platform desktop app.
I want to set custom icon when i make build file and want to add product name on app.
But when i **set custom icon, it work perfect in locally but when make it build then not work correctly**.
It give an error **default Electron icon is used  reason=application icon is not set**.

**Here is Background.js file**

```
'use strict'

import { app, protocol, BrowserWindow } from 'electron'
import { createProtocol } from 'vue-cli-plugin-electron-builder/lib'
import installExtension, { VUEJS_DEVTOOLS } from 'electron-devtools-installer'
const isDevelopment = process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production'


// Scheme must be registered before the app is ready
protocol.registerSchemesAsPrivileged([
    { scheme: 'app', privileges: { secure: true, standard: true } }
])

async function createWindow() {
    const path = require('path')
    const win = new BrowserWindow({
        webPreferences: {
            icon: path.join(__dirname, '../public/favicon.ico'),
            // Use pluginOptions.nodeIntegration, leave this alone
            // See nklayman.github.io/vue-cli-plugin-electron-builder/guide/security.html#node-integration for more info
            nodeIntegration: process.env.ELECTRON_NODE_INTEGRATION
        }
            
    })
    win.maximize();
    win.removeMenu();
    //win.setIcon(path.join(__dirname, '../public/favicon.ico'));
    if (process.env.WEBPACK_DEV_SERVER_URL) {
        // Load the url of the dev server if in development mode
        await win.loadURL(process.env.WEBPACK_DEV_SERVER_URL)
        if (!process.env.IS_TEST) win.webContents.openDevTools()
    } else {
        createProtocol('app')
        // Load the index.html when not in development
        win.loadURL('app://./index.html')
       
    }
    
}

// Quit when all windows are closed.
app.on('window-all-closed', () => {
    // On macOS it is common for applications and their menu bar
    // to stay active until the user quits explicitly with Cmd + Q
    if (process.platform !== 'darwin') {
        app.quit()
    }
})

app.on('activate', () => {
    // On macOS it's common to re-create a window in the app when the
    // dock icon is clicked and there are no other windows open.
    if (BrowserWindow.getAllWindows().length === 0) createWindow()
})

// This method will be called when Electron has finished
// initialization and is ready to create browser windows.
// Some APIs can only be used after this event occurs.
app.on('ready', async () => {
    if (isDevelopment && !process.env.IS_TEST) {
        // Install Vue Devtools
        try {
            await installExtension(VUEJS_DEVTOOLS)
        } catch (e) {
            console.error('Vue Devtools failed to install:', e.toString())
        }
    }
    createWindow()
})

// Exit cleanly on request from parent process in development mode.
if (isDevelopment) {
    if (process.platform === 'win32') {
        process.on('message', (data) => {
            if (data === 'graceful-exit') {
                app.quit()
            }
        })
    } else {
        process.on('SIGTERM', () => {
            app.quit()
        })
    }
}
```

**And Package.Json is**

```
{
  "name": "pmptestengine",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "serve": "vue-cli-service serve",
    "build": "vue-cli-service build",
    "lint": "vue-cli-service lint",
    "electron:build": "vue-cli-service electron:build",
    "electron:serve": "vue-cli-service electron:serve",
    "postinstall": "electron-builder install-app-deps",
    "postuninstall": "electron-builder install-app-deps"
  },
  "main": "background.js",
"devDependencies": {
    "@vue/cli-plugin-babel": "~4.5.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-eslint": "~4.5.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-router": "~4.5.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-vuex": "~4.5.0",
    "@vue/cli-service": "~4.5.0",
    "babel-eslint": "^10.1.0",
    "electron": "^11.0.0",
    "electron-devtools-installer": "^3.1.0",
    "eslint": "^6.7.2",
    "eslint-plugin-vue": "^6.2.2",
    "vue-cli-plugin-electron-builder": "~2.0.0-rc.6",
    "vue-template-compiler": "^2.6.11"
  }
}
```

Comment: Read this for a minute it will help : https://www.electron.build/icons

Comment: I do not understand this document. How to implement.

Comment: You must set configuration for Build for every OS (Windows - Linux - macOS) or even the OS that you will build your App for

Comment: """"scripts": {
    "serve": "vue-cli-service serve",
    "build": "vue-cli-service build",
    "lint": "vue-cli-service lint",
    "electron:build": "vue-cli-service electron:build",
    "electron:serve": "vue-cli-service electron:serve",
    "postinstall": "electron-builder install-app-deps",
    "postuninstall": "electron-builder install-app-deps"
  },"""

Comment: Here is already build and electron build variable. When i add new build  key then it conflict

Comment: Hi .. Sorry for late reply .. This is the part of build for My Web Browser created by Electron JS .. Just add this inside your package.json .. But Edit to match your Project : https://jsfiddle.net/h9rkp2q3/1/

Comment: 'ERR_ELECTRON_BUILDER_INVALID_CONFIGURATION'

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/230937/discussion-between-kevin-m-mansour-and-ahsan-farooq).

Comment: Thanks  @Kevin M. Mansour

Comment: Thanks @KevinM.Mansour I got a solution.

Comment: When i work in electron vue js . We make a file vue.cofig.js and write this line of code inside it

Comment: Great! .. I recommend to post it in Stack Overflow to help new people in the site .. Good Luck :)

Comment: ok  i post different question about electron vue js

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**When we work in electron vue js. we add new file vue.config.js and paste these line of code.**

```
module.exports = {
        pluginOptions: {
        electronBuilder: {
            builderOptions: {
                productName: "News App",
                appId: 'test.com',
                win: {
                    "target": [
                        "nsis"
                    ],
                  icon: 'public/svg.png',
                  "requestedExecutionLevel": "requireAdministrator"
                },
                "nsis": {
                    "installerIcon": "public/favicon.ico",
                    "uninstallerIcon": "public/favicon.ico",
                    "uninstallDisplayName": "CPU Monitor",
                    "license": "license.txt",
                    "oneClick": false,
                    "allowToChangeInstallationDirectory": true
                }
            },
        },
    },
    }
```